# tsconfig to enable intellisense in vscode for node 14

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have the following tsconfig.json in a TypeScript npm package that I maintain.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2020",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": ["es2020"],
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "strict": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
    },
    "exclude": ["scripts/", "test/"]
}
```

I export all functions, classes, and utilities via default export in index.ts

```
export default {
   CoolClass,
   CoolClass2,
   utils: {
      utilFunction,
      utilFunction2,
   }   ​
}
```

I am using the npm package in a normal node v14 project without `"type": "module"`. I have eslint enabled. I usually get pretty good intellisense for npm packages that I use.

I don't know why but for the compiled TypeScript from that package, I do not get any intellisense.

```
const { default as package } = require('mypackage');

const myClass = new package.CoolClass()
// if I hover over CoolClass, it shows (property) SpeechResponse: an
myClass. // if I hover over my class, it shows const resp: any
```

Also, typed object params loose their intellisense which is very annoying.

```
package.utils.utilFunction({ typedProperty: ... })
// I don't get any autocompletion for possible properties
```

I am not sure if I need to alter my tsconfig.json or if the export default might be the issue. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please verify you have added the following, when publishing your typescript package to npm. If you had missed out any of the mentioned points, then please add and test out the published package for intellisense:

- Add `"declaration": true` to your `tsconfig.json`. This tells TypeScript to emit an .d.ts definitions file along with your compiled JavaScript.
- Point out the main file and types file(The filename of your .d.ts file will be the same as your main entry point.) in `package.json`, like so(assuming your `outDir` in tsconfig is a folder named `dist`):

```json
"main": "dist/index.js",
"types": "dist/index.d.ts",
```

- Add prepublish key to package.json to compile using tsc before publish:

```json
"prepublish": "tsc"
```

Comment: Thanks so much! dist/index.d.ts was missing in package.json. It worked!